# Using markevery kwarg with axhline

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I was trying to plot a vertical line with markers on it using `ax.axvline` but the markers only show up on the bottom and top of the figure. I have played around with the `markevery` [kwarg](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markevery) but it does not seem to have any effect when I change it even though it works for a normal line plot. Does anyone know if this is because no discrete values are specified along the axis or am I just doing something wrong?

I realize that I can plot a vertical line on my own and specify the markers, but I figure given the purpose of `axvline` I should use it.

Here is an example code of what I am talking about:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-10,10)
y = x**2-15.


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

ax.plot(y,x) #Test curve

ax.plot(2+np.zeros(len(x)),x,marker='X',markevery=1) #another way to plot what I want.

ax.axvline(0,c='r',marker='X',markevery=1) #markerevery doesn't seem to work

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The axvline consists of only two points, the start and the end. So you cannot mark any points that aren't there.

Comment: Thats what I suspected, thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by ImportanceofBeingErnest, the `markerevery`kwarg does not apply for `axvline` or `axhline` because there are technically only 2 points used to draw the line at the boundaries.